# Debian 8 | Windows issues : How to manage high definition?

Tags: debian, gnome

I have an Ultrabook which has 1080p definition and I'm running Debian 8 Jessie (and the Gnome desktop environment). The problem is that each windows is very little due to the high definition and I can't find a way to fix it. (Without decreasing the definition) Microsoft Windows 10 manage perfectly that and even on Ubuntu we can fix this problem in the options.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you didn't specify your environment close enough.
It depends on window manager. There are several desktop environments for Debian, and each uses different window manager.
For example, Gnome uses Unity, LXDE uses openbox and so on.
That means, you should search how to increase windows size in your window manager.
I wrote this as answer, because I can't comment yet.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry i have Gnome environment.

Comment: That's ok. As I was doing the research, I found out that gnome has integrated support for HiDPI in the Tweaking tool, or what's it's name. Look in Window section, and the last entry Window Scale. Try to play with it.

Comment: Thanks to you i finnally found a way to fix it. The exact tool name that you're talking about is gnome-tweak-tool and i didn't know anything about it ! But when I change the window scale (1 by defaut or plus) it's way too big... But i search a little bit with these informations and i found this : https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI. In section 1.1 everything is explained ! Basically i can change the windows scale with xrandr command line. But now my problem is that the changes aren't saved after rebooting...